# Does this differential equation has an explicit solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y'(t)=e^{-y^2(t)}$ and $y(0)=0.$ Is there an explicit solution of such differential equation? Or is there a bound for $y$?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3De%5E(-y%5E2)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-y^2}$$ 
$$e^{y^2}dy=dt$$
$$\int e^{y^2}dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erfi}(y)=t+c$$
$$\text{erfi}(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t+c)$$
$$y(t)=\text{erfi}^{-1}(x(t)) \qquad\text{where}\qquad x(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t+c)$$
erfi is a known special function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

$\text{erfi}^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function of erfi.

The above closed form solution of the ODE cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions.